# Migrating from OAuth1 to OAuth2

Tags: oauth, soundcloud

We have an existing application on SoundCloud that was created some time ago and set up to use OAuth1. Recently we needed to expand SoundCloud-related functionality and, because of some problems with the old library, had to upgrade to new cocoa-api-wrapper library that uses OAuth2 client.

The problem now is that we cannot access our application with its key/secret because of the different version of OAuth. While it is possible to set up new application and get new key/secret pair, we wouldn't want to lose all the data associated with the current application.

Is there a way to have the same SoundCloud application accessible with both versions of OAuth (OAuth1 is still being used)? If not, what's the best way to handle this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can migrate an OAuth1 token to an OAuth2 token by sending a POST request to the following endpoint:

`https://api.soundcloud.com/oauth2/token`

with the following parameters:

- client_id='YOUR_CLIENT_ID'
- client_secret='YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
- grant_type='oauth1_token'
- refresh_token='OAUTH1_TOKEN'

The response will contain an OAuth2 token (as well as `expires_in`, `scope`, `refresh_token`).