# Migrating to gmail oauth2

Tags: python, django, oauth, gmail, oauth-2.0

We are a python/django shop and we have a connection to gmail using the depracated oauth approach which returns an token/secret for every user. We have to move to oauth2 before 2015 because of google deprecation policy but there is no documentation about how to migrate, and making all our users reconnect their account is something we want to definitely avoid.

It's there a way to do this migration programmatically?

Comment: here are some links [oauth2](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_overview), [oauth](https://developers.google.com/gmail/oauth_protocol) (deprecated), a question related but not specific to gmail oauth service [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15303023/migrating-from-oauth1-to-oauth2), and well, tried some unsuccessful queries on google.

Comment: Since Google doesn't have a migration document, I would test using a OAuth token in an OAuth2 request and see if it works. You might be able to keep the same key and just migrate to the new services.

Comment: I will try this out and let everyone know, I doubt it will work but who knows, let the hacking begin? hah

Comment: @Hassek: Good luck! :-)  If you do find a solution, don't be afraid to post an answer to your own question.  That will at least help the next person who has the same question. :-)

Comment: I tried what Mark S. suggested and simply re-using the token does not work, at least not as an OAuth 2 Bearer token. Maybe they support it as another token type but can't find any mention of it. If they allow a token migration grant like SoundCloud the docs for it are very well hidden.